# Any way to check if my AirPort card is going bad MacPro 2013?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, mac-pro

Every day for the past couple days, my WiFi on my MacPro 2013 running Mojave 10.14.6 has spontaneously vanished. The signal strength icon in the menu bar goes gray, and the status is "Wi-Fi looking for networks" (even though it lists all of my local networks).

The only solution is to reboot the machine.

Beside simply this random crass behavior, is there perhaps something in the logs I could look at that would show some tell tales that this is, indeed, what's happening? I would like perchance some additional evidence before I drag it in to the Genius Bar with "yea is sometimes does this" to try and narrow down the issue.

In the end, they may simply swap out the card. I don't know if it will fail a diagnostic, or if it's just happy happy until it decides "No, not happy".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple Diagnostics to run a hardware check on your computer. Instructions for doing that are [found here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731).  Your computer is on the borderline for computers using Apple Diagnostics. If you computer is from before June 2013 you have to use Apple Hardware Test. There is a link in the reference I included for this older hardware test.

If you are using an Apple Base Station, you can check that you have the latest software for your base station. [This link](https://support.apple.com/guide/aputility/keep-your-base-station-up-to-date-aprt2704/mac) describes what you should do to keep your airport base station up to date.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I ran the diagnostic, and it return a clean bill of health. Since this seems to be intermittent, I was wondering if there's something in a log somewhere I might be looking for that may provide insight.